# Relation between max-margin and vector support in SVM

Tags: machine-learning, scikit-learn, svm

I am reading the mathematical formulation of SVM and on many sources I found this idea that **"max-margin hyperplane is completely determined by those  \vec{x}_i which lie nearest to it. These  \vec{x}_i are called support vectors."**
Could an expert explain mathematically this consequence? please.

Comment: Section 3 of this excellent tutorial explains it very clearly: http://research.microsoft.com/pubs/67119/svmtutorial.pdf

Answer (score 0):

This is true only if you use [representation theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Representation_theory)

Your separation plane W can be represented as Sum(i= 1 to m) Alpha_i*phi(x_i)
Where m - number of examples in your train sample and x_i is example i. And Phi is function that maps x_i to some feature space.

So, your SVM algorithm will find vector Alpha=(Alpha_1...Alpha_m), -  alpha_i for x_i. Every x_i(example in train sample) that his alpha_i is NOT zero is **support vector** of W.

Hence the name - **SVM**.

What happens if your data is **separable**, is that you need only support vectors that are close to separation margin **W**, and all rest of the training set can be discarded(its alphas is 0).  Amount of support vectors that algorithm will use is depends on complexity of data and kerenl you using.